# c# EF6 asynchronous saving/editing

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to save roughly 20,000 records and it takes an unforgivable amount of time to finish. What is the more optimal way of achieving this?

Here's what I currently have:

```
public async Task SaveOrUpdateItemAsync(List<DepartmentalizedItem> departmentalizedItems)
{
    using(WarehouseContext dbContext = new WarehouseContext())
    {
        using(SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(20))
        {
            var tasks = departmentalizedItems.Select(async item =>
            {
                await throttler.WaitAsync();
                if (item.PK_DepartmentalizedItemId == 0)
                    dbContext.DepartmentalizedItems.Add(item);
                else
                {
                    var deptItem = await dbContext.DepartmentalizedItems.FindAsync(item.PK_DepartmentalizedItemId);
                    dbContext.Entry(deptItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
                }
                throttler.Release();
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

I've also tried Parallel.ForEach but I'm having synchronization issues.

Thank you.

Comment: You could check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state#insert-or-update-pattern) about entity state in order to avoid the Find call.

Comment: You should take a look at BulkInsert https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-insert

Comment: @Hasse that seems to be a paid library. Any alternatives?

Comment: @StavrosZotalis I've tried this, but I encountered an Error. "failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.". I remembered that this same error was the reason why I am not using the EntityState.

Comment: @redz0323 Test this nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.BulkInsert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all answers, comments and suggestion. All of those has been taken into consideration and I have finally arrived to a more optimal way of saving/editing 20,000 records in bulk. As suggested by Hasse, I took a peek on BulkInsert, but this is a paid library, thus I tried to find any alternatives and fortunately I found N.EntityFramework.Extensions.

Here's what solved my issue:

```
public async Task BulkSaveAndUpdateAsync(List<DepartmentalizedItem> departmentalizedItems, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (WarehouseContext dbContext = new WarehouseContext())
        {
            var toAddItems = departmentalizedItems.Where(i => i.PK_DepartmentalizedItemId == 0);
            var toUpdateItems = departmentalizedItems.Where(i => i.PK_DepartmentalizedItemId > 0);
            await dbContext.BulkInsertAsync(toAddItems, cancellationToken);
            await dbContext.BulkUpdateAsync(toUpdateItems, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Insert**

You can use `AddRange` method to insert bulk data to db. It will not take that much time to save those in db.

If you are using `Add`, it is resizing the inner array gradually as needed (doubling), from the default starting size of 10 (IIRC).

`AddRange` checks size of added items and increases size of internal array only once.

**For Update**

You can use **`UpdateRange`** to update multiple records at single call. It will save your time to proceed the query.

**eg.**

```
public class abc
{
  public int propa {get;set;}
  public string propb {get;set;} 
} 

public bool AddUpdate(List<abc> abc)
{
  List<abc> added=new List<abc>();
  List<abc> updated=new List<abc>();
  foreach(var item in abc)
  {
    if(item.propa==0) // I considered that if propa has no value then it's new record to be added else updated
    {
      added.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
      updated.Add(item)
    }
  }
  if(added?.Any()??false)
  {
    _dbContext.abc.AddRange(added);
  }
  if(updated?.Any()??false)
  {
   _dbContext.abc.UpdateRange(added);
  }
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, that answers the saving part, sorry I wasn't specific enough, I mean saving and editing. As majority of the records are being edited. On my else statement, do you have any insight on how I can optimize it? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, if possible, can you please provide a sample snippet? I can't find an example on how to implement this on EF6. Thank you.

Comment: @redz0323 I update the example as well

Comment: **Note 1:** The AddRange and UpdateRange methods are not supported by plain EF6. They are part of EF6 Core. Furthermore I think that this solution will suffer from the same error "failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value." because as far as I can tell DepartmentalizedItem has navigational properties pointing to different unattached objects that share the same keys.
**Note 2:** Entity Framework 6 has lazy loading enabled by default.

Comment: He needs to use `AsNoTracking()` to avoid that issue. Thanks for note.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend some profiling to see what part is actually taking time. I would also recommend posting times and the size of the data you are adding to be able to estimate how reasonable the times are. "unforgivable amount of time" will depend on context and patience. See [Fastest way of inserting](https://Fastest%20Way%20of%20Inserting%20in%20Entity%20Framework) where the top post inserts 500k items in ~4 minutes.

A possible issue might be the FindAsync, if it needs to run a query for each item I would expect it to be quite slow. You could avoid this by querying all the items at once, something like:

```
var ids = departmentalizedItems.Select(i => i.PK_DepartmentalizedItemId).ToList();
var itemsById = dbContext.DepartmentalizedItems.Where(i => ids.Contains(i)).ToDictionary(i  => i.PK_DepartmentalizedItemId, i => i);
```

I would also get rid of the sempaphore and change it to a regular for-loop. `dbContext` is not thread safe, so whatever you are doing will not make it run in parallel, and you are only making your code harder to understand for no real gain.

Also note that `Async` will probably not make your code faster in any way. It is meant to hide latency, not improve performance. I would also consider splitting your items into chunks, and add some way to report progress to the user.

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes the await that you mentioned actually caused an exception.